# How to find a row with the same numeric value in each cell in a two dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm looking at a two dimensional array. I'd like to find out the index of all rows in which the numeric value in each cell equals 0. 
In the attached image you can see an example of a two dimensional array. My goal is to identify row 1 and 4 as there are only "0" entries in the cells of those rows.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if (Arrays.stream(a[i]).allMatch(x -> x == 0))
        indexes.add(i);
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to upvote and accept answer!